# Is this hypothesis regarding irreducible polynomials necessary?

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I'm working through Rotman's Galois Theory book, and one of the exercises is:

> Let $F$ be a field and let  $p(x)\in F[x]$  be irreducible. If $g(x)\in F[x]$  is not constant, then either $(p(x), g(x)) =  1$ or  $p(x) | g(x)$.

This statement is straightforward to prove, but as far as I can tell, the requirement that $g$ be non-constant is unnecessary. If $g$ is constant, then $(p,g)=1$, so the statement seems to still hold. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AlexWertheim But $p\mid 0$ for all $p$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: right, for whatever reason I had transposed the division (I was thinking $0 \mid p$). Thanks, deleting...

Comment: @quasi Hm, but "and" can only occur if $p$ is also constant, hence hardly irreducible. -- As $p$ is irreducible, $(p(x))$ is maximal, hence $F[x]/(p(x))$ is a field. The image of *any* polynomial  $g(x)\in F[x]$ in that field is either non-zero or zero. No further assumptions on $g$ are needed.